# ggpubr: how to obtain summary statistics for violin / boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm new to the `ggpubr` package but have found it great so far. However, I haven't managed to work out how to get the calculated values (range, IQR etc) back from a boxplot. Normally the `$stats` argument would do this, but now all I get back is `NULL`.

```
p <- ggviolin(SIM.data, x = "data", y = "percent", fill = "gray80",
       add = "boxplot", add.params = list(fill = "white")) + 
     stat_compare_means(label.y = 25)

p$stats
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ggplot_build` and then take a look at the `data` element.

```
pb <- ggplot_build(p)
# str(pb, 1)
pb$data[[2]] # geomBoxplot is the second layer
#  ymin lower middle upper ymax      outliers notchupper notchlower x PANEL group ymin_final ymax_final xmin xmax weight colour  fill size alpha shape linetype
#1  2.9 3.200    3.4 3.675  4.2      4.4, 2.3   3.506137   3.293863 1     1     1        2.3        4.4  0.9  1.1      1  black white  0.5     1    19    solid
#2  2.0 2.525    2.8 3.000  3.4                 2.906137   2.693863 2     1     2        2.0        3.4  1.9  2.1      1  black white  0.5     1    19    solid
#3  2.5 2.800    3.0 3.175  3.6 3.8, 2.2, 3.8   3.083792   2.916208 3     1     3        2.2        3.8  2.9  3.1      1  black white  0.5     1    19    solid
```

**data**

```
library(ggpubr)
p <- ggviolin(iris, 
              x = "Species",
              y = "Sepal.Width",
              fill = "gray80",
              add = "boxplot",
              add.params = list(fill = "white")) + 
  stat_compare_means()
```

---

You might want to read [Creating ggplot2 Extensions](https://rud.is/books/creating-ggplot2-extensions/demystifying-ggplot2.html#the-ggplot_built-object) from fantastic [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr).

Comment: Thanks markus - works perfectly! Also great tip on the article.